Showing the results of each loop on the same figure after a small pause using Python
I am trying to show the result of each iteration of the for loop on the same figure after a small certain pause of time.
This is my code:
#import necessary libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import time

#create a signal
L = 10 #length of domain
n = 2048 # number of points
t = np.linspace(0,L,num=n) #domain variable
St = (3*np.sin(2*t)+1.5*np.sin(5*t)+6*np.cos(20*(t))) #signal

#create a function to be plotted on top of the previous signal
m = 100 #number of points
tau = np.linspace(0,L,m) #iteration variable

#create a figure
plt.figure

#slide the new function over the signal
#show the result of each iteration on the same figure
for i in range(len(tau)):
    #define the new function
    #Define Gabor window/Gaussian 
    tslide = t-tau[i]
    width = 10
    g = np.exp(-(width*tslide)**2)
    #plot the signal and the sliding function
    plt.plot(t, St,color = 'k')
    plt.plot(t, g,color = 'r')
    time.sleep(0.1)

plt.show()

Any help would be appreciated.

This looks like the feature you need

Can you explain what's wrong? It seems to me that your code is good. Be sure to state any problems/errors you encountered and also add the error message(s) and traceback formatted as code.
